# Joint PDF and CDF two dimensional

Tags: statistics

> Let $X$ and $Y$ have joint pdf $f(x,y) = 4e^{-2(x+y)}$ for $0 < x < \infty$, $0 < y < \infty$, and zero otherwise.
>
> (a) Find the CDF of $W = X + Y$
>
> (b) Find the joint pdf of $U = X/Y$ and $V=X$
>
> (c) Find the marginal pdf of $U$

Could someone show me the *statistics* behind setting up the integration? I can do the computation myself. So for instance, for (b). I will at least need the Jacobian, $$\begin{vmatrix}
U_x & U_y\\ 
V_x & V_y
\end{vmatrix} = \dfrac{-X}{Y^2}$$

Then subbing, I get $f(u,v)=4e^{2(\frac{v}{u}+v)}$

And for the marginal, I am not continuing until I am sure (b) is right otherwise I will waste my time doing unnecessary computation.

> (a) $$\int_{0}^{w} \int_{0}^{w-x} 4e^{-2(x+y)}dydx$$

Thanks

Comment: Currently there is a typo in the problem. The proposed joint density has infinite integral. I do not know what is intended, though $4e^{-2(x+y)}$ would be a valid joint density.

Comment: No the bounds are intended. I am reading through a similiar problem and I understand where you are coming from

Comment: OK, but do read your density function carefully. In my display, it reads $4e^{2(x+y)}$.

Comment: It is missing a minius sign, you are correct thank you

Comment: Jacobians are not supposed to be used as plug-and-chug instruments as you have done. For _what_ values of $(x,y)$ does your expression hold?

Comment: @DilipSarwate, isn't that given? Only positive values are okay. I'll edit my new progress

Comment: No, it is **not** always a given that new bivariate random variable $(U,V)$ has the same range as $(X,Y)$, though it does happen to be true in this instance. For example, $(X+Y,X-Y)$ has different range than $(X,Y)$. So, it is important to figure out what the range is in each case, and at least mention what the range is. You cannot simply say $f(u,v)=4e^{2(v/u+v)}$ without any qualifications because most people would assume that the range is the entire plane in such cases. Note, by the way, that you do not have a valid density $f(u,v)$ _even_ if you say that $u, v > 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also notice that the joint pdf density split into a function of the form $f(x)g(y)$, meaning that they are two independent gaussian random variables. Then everything become much easy with convolutions and relatives ...

Comment: **gaussian** random variables?